# Can I change what the button on my earphone does?

Tags: customization

I have a Samsung Galaxy Young with Gingerbread. I also have a pair of Samsung earphones. Is there any way I can change the pause button so that it functions as a previous track button?

Comment: I don't think an app can recognize the pause button alone because the button also has the functionality assigned for Play button too. You can try double or triple click to change next/prev tracks. But is based on the heaset/ phone compatibility. My phone supports triple click for the previous track. :)

Answer (score 2):

this app is able to change your earphones button function to whatever you want( open apps, toggle flashlight, control volume...), here's the the link https://apkpure.com/jays-headset-control/se.jays.headsetcontrol

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to answer it now.. I hope it will help someone else..
Try [Button Mapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton&hl=en_IN&gl=US).. With this you can remap ALL hardware buttons! Remember to turn off battery optimization for this app else no hardware keys will work if this app is killed and you'll have to reboot it or open the app again..